I cannot enable information_schema in datafusion-java
I am trying to play with dataflow-java.
When I try to run the following code:
context.sql("select * from information_schema.tables").thenComposeAsync(DataFrame::show).join();

I get error
Error during planning: table 'datafusion.information_schema.tables' not found

So, I tried this replace select by command SHOW TABLES:
context.sql("SHOW TABLES").thenComposeAsync(DataFrame::show).join();

and got error:
SHOW TABLES is not supported unless information_schema is enabled

This was a good tip because if information_schema is not enabled there should be a way to enable it. So, I found this document that says that there is property datafusion.catalog.information_schema that is false by default. Also this document explains that the properties could be configured using environment variables.

The name of the environment variable is the option’s key, transformed
to uppercase and with periods replaced with underscores. For example,
to configure datafusion.execution.batch_size you would set the
DATAFUSION_EXECUTION_BATCH_SIZE environment variable.

So, I have added the following environment variable: DATAFUSION_CATALOG_INFORMATION_SCHEMA and set it value to true and then to TRUE but noting helped. I still get the same error messages.
BTW everything works well with the datafusion-cli.
So, what's wrong? Is this something that does not work in datafusion-java or I am doing something wrong?
